# Automated Email Notification in Microsoft SQL Management Studio : Editing a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a couple of Automatic email notifications,that gets sent our from Microsoft SQL Management Studio
There is a SQL Query for each notification
Each Query is connected with a certain "Time Schedule".
The Query gets send once a certain time has passed.
We need to edit this schedule to adjsut the new time in the Query

Please can I get guidance on how this is done?

Comment: try like this in where DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@Run_time,rsh_time) as Runinterval,GETDATE() as date

Comment: Nope,that is not what I am looking for.I want to find out how we can access 'saved queries' used for automatic notications.How do I navigate to these saved queries